# Calling a function and assigning the value inside a while loop. Dice homework problem

Tags: javascript

I'm getting undefined back everytime. I can't seem to get any out put for dice 1 and dice2.

I changed the while statement to a for statement to see if that was the issue. i tried to put in the outer while loop the condition (numberOfSides < 3 && dice1 != dice2 but that would continue to prompt me to enter a new numberOfSides. I've basically messed around with this thing trying rearranging variables.

```
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)) + min;
}
var numberOfSides2 = numberOfSides
var dice2 = 0;
var dice1 = 0;
var numberOfRoles = 0;
var numberOfSides = parseInt(prompt("how many sides does your dice have, "));
while (numberOfSides < 3) {
        numberOfSides = parseInt(prompt("enter the amount a number greater than 3, "));
    }
while (dice1 != dice2) {
    dice1 === getRandomInt(numberOfSides, numberOfSides2);
    dice2 === getRandomInt(numberOfSides, numberOfSides2);
    ++numberOfRoles}
    if (dice1 != dice2) {
        alert(dice1);
    }
```

I keep getting the message undefined.  The more I try to fix it and rewrite it the more errors I seem to make. I am supposed to make it look like this but first, I want to make sure I can make it output something after running a function.

How many sides on your dice? -10
Sorry, that's not a valid size value. Please choose a positive number.
How many sides on your dice? 6

Thanks! Here we go ...

1. die number 1 is 5 and die number 2 is 3.
2. die number 1 is 2 and die number 2 is 2.
3. die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 5.
4. die number 1 is 5 and die number 2 is 1.
   ... (these triple dots mean the output keeps going, but just not for the sample, so we save space)
5. die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 1.

You got snake eyes! Finally! On try number 16!
Along the way you rolled doubles 5 times
The average roll for die #1 was 2.95
The average roll for die #2 was 3.20

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see the point of the numberOfSides2 variable as the getRandomInt function would always take 1 as its min value and the input from the user as the max value.
2. '===' is a comparison operator so you can't use it to assign a dice number to a random integer.
3. It is not quiet clear at what point you want the loop to stop so the following code stops when the users rolls a double.

```js
getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)) + min;
};

let numOfSides = parseInt(prompt('how many sides does your dice have, '));
let dice1 = getRandomInt(1, numOfSides);
let dice2 = getRandomInt(1, numOfSides);
let numOfRoles = 1;

while (numOfSides < 3) {
  numOfSides = parseInt(prompt('enter the amount a number greater than 3, '));
}

while (dice1 != dice2) {
  dice1 = getRandomInt(1, numOfSides);
  dice2 = getRandomInt(1, numOfSides);
  numOfRoles++;
  console.log(dice1);
  console.log(dice2);
  console.log('---');
}

if (dice1 === dice2) {
  console.log('matching pair is ' + dice1);
}
```

To answer you question, you code would always return 0 for the value of dice1 and dice2 because you are using '===' instead of '='.